# QTableWidget.cellActivated() signal not working?

Tags: qt4, signals, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I have tried to re-implement the QTableWidget.cellActivated(row, number) using PyQt4, to catch the coordinates of the currently active cell. The sample below does not work as expected, the method is not activated when a cell is clicked. Have I done something wrong?

```
class DictionaryTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def cellActivated(self, row, column):
        print row, column
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtablewidget.html#cellActivated), i see:

> **void QTableWidget::cellActivated ( int row, int column ) [signal]**
>
> This
> signal is emitted when the cell specified by row and column has been
> activated This function was introduced in Qt 4.1.

This is a signal, not an event. So you don't need to [re]implement `cellActivated` method (it's not a method, it's a class attribute of signal type). You need to connect to the signal:

```
class DictionaryTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, language_code, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.cellActivated.connect(self.handleCellActivated)

    def handleCellActivated(self, row, column):
        print row, column
```

Comment: The connection problem is solved, but the signal is emitted only as I press Enter on a highlighted cell. I expected the signal to be emitted each time a new cell is selected (using tab or arrow-keys or mouse-click). The cellEntered does not either track this.

Comment: @Benjamin, try something like `self.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)`

Comment: Yes, I figured out the `selectionChanged` is what I needed thanks :)